# PHP - IF statement in a return? correct syntax?

Tags: php, syntax, return

So I have a return in one of my functions:

```
return '<i class="'.$class.'" style="size:'.$size.';"></i>';
```

However, I don't want to display style if size is not populated, so I need to do an `if $size`

Is this possible to do? I couldn't find an example in the manual.

Sorry I should clarify - I still want the return to take place if $size is empty, but I don't want style=" to be there, so pseudo code:

return: $class if $size ( $size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return sprintf('<i class="%s"%s></i>',           // result using %s palceholders
  $class,                                        // first %s placeholder
  !empty($size) ? 'style="size:'.$size.';"' : '' // second %s placeholder
);
```

[Inline ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) that will only include the `style="..."` attribute (as a whole) when `$size` is not empty.

Outcomes:

```
/*
 * Where size is empty
 */
$class = 'foo';
$size = null;

// Result:
<i class="foo"></i>

/*
 * Where size is populated
 */
$class = 'foo';
$size = 'large';

// Result:
<i class="foo" style="size:large;"></i>
```

Comment: @user: the above handles that.

Comment: Thanks brad - what are the differences between your method and the one posted by @Sirko?

Comment: @user319940: Really not much difference other than Sirko keeps everything in one line concatenated and I used `sprintf` to format the result.